# How ro apply Keda and hpa both in kubernetes autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa, keda

Need some help in K8s autoscaling. I want to have a mixed kubernetes autosclaing policy with HPA and Kubernetes Event Driven Autoscaling(Keda).

Policy should be like:
Run 2 pods in the night time ( 10 PM to 8 AM)

2. Run minimum N number of pods in the day time (8 AM to 10 PM) and on the top of it I can further apply CPU based (HPA) OR Kafka Lag based (Keda) autoscaling policy to go upto max M pods.

As of now We can apply Day/Night Keda based policy which can have fixed N number of  pods in the night time and M number of pods in the day time. I can't apply further autoscaling on these M pods in the day time.